# Use same scale for 3D pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to set the same scale for the X and Y axis on a 3D plot. Here is a sample plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X = np.array([-3, 5, 6])
Y = np.array([14, -2, -31])
Z = np.array([0.1, 0, -0.1])

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

The scale for the X and Y axis is such that they take up the same amount of space even though the true scale of the Y axis is larger than that of the X axis.

How do I make it so that they have an equal scale?

Edit: ax.set_xlim(Y.min(), Y.max()) worked.

Comment: To set the x-axis and y-axis to the same scale, add the following settings. `ax.set_xlim(Y.min(), Y.max())`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer above you can use `set_box_aspect`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X = np.array([-3, 5, 6])
Y = np.array([14, -2, -31])
Z = np.array([0.1, 0, -0.1])

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect([1,1,1])       #aspect ratio x,y,z
ax.plot(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

[image: example figure]